# Getting the current fragment position using state pager of actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a working state pager project using actionbarsherlock but I'm having trouble with getting the current fragment that was displayed. Is it possible to get the position of the current fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. If you are using a ViewPager you can do that :

```
_viewPager.getCurrentItem();
```

or that

```
_pageListener = new PageListener();
_viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(_pageListener);
```

and keep trace of current page with something like that :

```
private int _currentPage;

    private static class PageListener extends SimpleOnPageChangeListener{
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Log.i(TAG, "page selected " + position);
                   _currentPage = position;
        }
    }
```

Or else you can easily do that with a TabAdapter like this :

```
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context               mContext;
        private final ActionBar             mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager             mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo>    mTabs   = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo {
            private final Class<?>  clss;
            private final Bundle    args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {

                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {

            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            ((SherlockFragmentActivity) mContext).supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    }
```

You only need to keep the current page with one/or two of the methods. For example in **onTabSelected**

hope it helps you
good luck